# Can Chrome apps be set as default editor for a file type?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm currently doing some research for a potential personal project which aims to be the default editor of it's own file format. Due to some desired requirements, it's nature and personal preference I'd be implementing as a chrome app and I was wondering whether you can register a Chrome app as the default application for a file type system wide.

Registering it as available editor in Google Drive and other cloud storage solutions that allow it is nice and I can use an 'open file' dialog for getting user's local documents available for the app but a tighter, more traditional integration would be preferable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is possible at the moment on ChromeOS. There are bugs to log this on other operating systems, the first of which will be Windows.

To support this there are manifest entries for declaring your app can handle files, but these are not yet documented (we need to fix that).

Relevant bugs:

File handler registration on Windows: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130455

Documentation: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=192536

Comment: Also related but for URLs rather than local files: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111422

Comment: file_handlers is now documented here: http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/manifest.html#file_handlers

Comment: also in a similar situation to the OP. If this get's done, you can say goodbye to operating system specific apps. Think about it, sync your chrome, and all your apps are there ready on any pc, combine this with google drive, sheesh, TAKEOVER!

Comment: @sowbug those are classic HTTP urls, any clue if it's possible to register custom url-handlers? for example _magnet:_ or _mailto:_ (on all the websites of course)

Comment: We don't currently have a plan to implement protocol handlers. I don't recall the reason why we went down the url_handler route rather than letting Chrome Apps be default protocol handlers. Please file a feature request at crbug.com/new, and we'll think it over.

Comment: What's the current situation now? Is it possible yet to do so on Windows? What about Linux?